# PHP add items dynamically to a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to read some upstream data from a cable modem via snmpwalk.
(us channel id, us channel freq /MHz/, us channel width /MHz/).

In Docsis 3.0 mode i get at least two "records" (but max. 8), like this example:

```
4; 52; 6.4   // first upstream channel record
3; 45; 6.4   // second upstream channel record
```

So i do not know the numbers of the received "records" and i would like to solve this with multi-dimensional arrays and add items dynamically.

When i get all "records", then i would like to sort them by 'us channel id', so the result should look like this:

```
3; 45; 6.4
4; 52; 6.4
```

I know that this is solvable with string concatenation, but i prefer arrays.

Comment: You receive this lines per row or at once? If you give me that information I am glad to help you.

Comment: in which format you are receiving data ? string, array object ??

Comment: Make an array out of the record using `explode`. Then add it to your multidimensional array with `$array[] = $row;`

Comment: I get the input the from a snmpwalk output like this: Array (
 [transmission.127.1.1.2.1.1.4] => 4
 [transmission.127.1.1.2.1.1.80] => 3
 [transmission.127.1.1.2.1.2.4] => 52000000
 [transmission.127.1.1.2.1.2.80] => 45000000
 [transmission.127.1.1.2.1.3.4] => 6400000
 [transmission.127.1.1.2.1.3.80] => 6400000
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the information given I wrote this answer

Use a foreach to get the array,

```
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
        $channel_array['channel_id'] = $row['channel_id'];
        $channel_array['channel_freq'] = $row['channel_freq'];
        $channel_array['channel_width'] = $row['channel_width'];
    }
```

your array should look like this

```
Array = (

 [0] = array (
    [channel_id] => 4
    [channel_freq] => 52
    [channel_width] => 6.4
 )
  [1] = array (
    [channel_id] => 3
    [channel_freq] => 45
    [channel_width] => 6.4
 )
```

If you want to sort by channel_id, first create a separate array of channel_ids:

```
foreach ($channel_array as $channel) {    
   $channel_ids[] = $channel['channel_id'];
 }
```

Then use

```
array_multisort($channel_ids, SORT_ASC, $channel_array);
```

Comment: hi, and how can i print for example the freq: 45?